# Help with Replacing characters with text string chops of last character of string

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql

I need assistance with fixing a replace statement that truncates the last character of the string.  The original string (Question_Text) contains HTML characters and other erroneous characters that need to be cleaned up.  I included a multiple Replace statement within the Function.  it is the Function I need assistance with.

As you can see in the sample data, Question_Text2 has been cleaned up, except it cuts of the last character.  Along with the removal of erroneous characters in the middle of some of the questions (see ID = 12165).  What am I doing wrong?

I have include code to create the sample data results after the function has been used to illustrate the problem.

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tblQuestionsSample]    Script Date: 12/10/2021 5:12:16 PM ******/
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tblQuestionsSample]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[tblQuestionsSample]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tblQuestionsSample]    Script Date: 12/10/2021 5:12:16 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblQuestionsSample](
    [QuestionsRecID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Question_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Question_Text] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Question_Text2] [varchar](1000) NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.[QuestionsRecID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [QuestionsRecID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblQuestionsSample]
           ([Question_ID]
           ,[Question_Text]
           ,[Question_Text2])
     VALUES
        (11603,'<p>Date/Time</p>','Date/Tim')
        ,(11632,'<p>Attachments</p>','Attachment')
        ,(12166,'<p>Employee ID</p>','Employee I')
        ,(12166,'<p>Work Related?</p>','Work Related')
        ,(12165,'<p>Date &amp; Time of injury/onset illness?</p>','Date &amp; Time of injury/onset illness')
        ,(12165,'<p>Full Injury/Illness Description</p>','Full Injury/Illness Descriptio')
        ,(12165,'<p>Job Title</p>','Job Titl')
go
```

Results of query:

```
| id   |  question_text|                                Question_Text2| 
| ---- | -------- | -------------------------------------------------- |
| 11603| <p>Date/Time</p>|                               Date/Tim|
| 11632| <p>Attachments</p> |                            Attachment|
| 12166| <p>Employee ID</p> |                            Employee I|
| 12166| <p>Work Related?</p>|                            Work Related|
| 12165| <p>Date &amp; Time of injury/onset illness?</p>| Date &amp; Time of injury/onset illnes|
| 12165| <p>Full Injury/Illness Description</p>|       Full Injury/Illness Descriptio|
| 12165| <p>Job Title</p>|                                Job Titl|
```

As you can see I am using a function [dbo].[udf_StripHTML] to clean up the data:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_StripHTML] (@HTMLText VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Start INT
DECLARE @End INT
DECLARE @Length INT

SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText) SET @End = 
CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)) 
SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1 WHILE @Start > 0
AND @End > 0
AND @Length > 0
BEGIN
SET @HTMLText = STUFF(@HTMLText,@Start,@Length,'')
SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText) SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
END
--RETURN replace(REPLACE((@HTMLText),'&nbsp;',' '), '&#39;', '')
--RETURN replace(replace(LTRIM((@HTMLText)),'&nbsp;',' '), '&#39;','')
RETURN replace(substring(REPLACE(REPLACE(replace(ltrim(rtrim(@htmltext)),'&nbsp;',' '), '&#39',' '), '&amp;',''), charindex('.)',REPLACE(REPLACE(replace(ltrim(rtrim(@htmltext)),'&nbsp;',' '), '&#39;', ''), '&amp;','')), len(REPLACE(REPLACE(replace(ltrim(rtrim(@htmltext)),'&nbsp;',' '), '&#39;', ''), '&amp;',''))

END


Select [Question_ID]
,[Question_Text]
,[dbo].[udf_StripHTML]([question_text2])
From [dbo].[tblQuestionsSample]
WHERE  (question_text NOT LIKE '%Comments%') AND (question_text NOT LIKE '%Archived%')
```

I appreciate any assistance you may offer,

Karen

Comment: Your example says `[dbo].[udf_StripHTML]([question_text2])`, emphasis on you using the `question_text2` column. But your example `INSERT` statement for data sets that column to the value of `question_text` but with the last character cutoff already, e.g. when you say `VALUES (11603,'<p>Date/Time</p>','Date/Tim')`. So essentially you're initially inserting the data into your test table `dbo.tblQuestionsSample` incorrectly, before you even use your function.

Comment: May be construct a [fiddle](dbfiddle.uk/) with your function to spare people the trouble? All this `create table` stuff is irrelevant, as you can simply `select [dbo].[udf_StripHTML]('<p>Date/Time</p>')` for testing. Generally, parsing HTML with SQL is not fun; consider using proper tools for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your HTML is valid XHTML (and it appears to be so from the small sample provided), you can cast it to `xml` and then use `.value` with XQuery to parse it. This will do a far better job than mucking around with string manipulation and HTML escaping:

```sql
SELECT
  Question_Text_Parsed = TRY_CAST(Question_Text AS xml).value('(/p/text())[1]','nvarchar(1000)')
FROM tblQuestionsSample
```

| Question_ID | Question_Text_Parsed |
| --- | --- |
| 11603 | Date/Time |
| 11632 | Attachments |
| 12166 | Employee ID |
| 12166 | Work Related? |
| 12165 | Date & Time of injury/onset illness? |
| 12165 | Full Injury/Illness Description |
| 12165 | Job Title |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f76bf698365ae20304fc16e88bf41478)

Comment: Thank you I have been searching for this answer for several weeks and you gave me the best results..  This really did the trick.

Comment: Need to reopen this question.  I am still having issues with the Try_Cast is returning some null values.   It seem that some of data within the Question_Text does not apply to  XHTML, how do I rectified this issue.

Comment: You would have to find a different method. You may be able to mangle it into XHTML, you may not. I suggest you post a *new* question showing data that is representative of invalid values