# SQL Server Try_Cast returns Null value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, functions

[Related Questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/303812/help-with-replacing-characters-with-text-string-chops-of-last-character-of-strin/303838#303838)

```
    ,TRY_CAST(Question_Text AS xml).value('(/p/text())[1]','nvarchar(1000)') AS Question_Text2
```

With the help of CharlieFace on my previous post I discovered the use of Try_Cast function within SQL Server.  I am still having issues with the Try_Cast is returning some **NULL** values. It seem that some of data within the Question_Text does not apply to XHTML, how do I rectified this issue.

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tblQuestionsSample]    Script Date: 12/10/2021 5:12:16 PM ******/
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tblQuestionsSample]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[tblQuestionsSample]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tblQuestionsSample]    Script Date: 12/10/2021 5:12:16 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblQuestionsSample](
    [QuestionsRecID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Question_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Question_Text] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Question_Text2] [varchar](1000) NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.[QuestionsRecID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [QuestionsRecID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblQuestionsSample]
           ([Question_ID]
           ,[Question_Text]
     VALUES
        (6571,'<p><span style="color: rgb(29, 88, 196); font-family: Raleway, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 700; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: 2; text-align: start; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-decoration-thickness: initial; text-decoration-style: initial; text-decoration-color: initial; display: inline !important; float: none;">Capstan Hoist EXPIRATION DATE</span></p>')
        ,(6554,'<p>Do you have a current &#39;Hazard &nbsp;Communications&#39; certification to submit for verification?</p>')
        ,(6505,'<p>92) SC - Utilities are Identified/Obtained Valid Locate Tickets/Are Guarded?&nbsp;</p>')
        ,(6569,'<p><span style="color: rgb(29, 88, 196); font-family: Raleway, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 700; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: 2; text-align: start; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-decoration-thickness: initial; text-decoration-style: initial; text-decoration-color: initial; display: inline !important; float: none;">Authorized Climber and Rescue EXPIRATION DATE</span></p>')
        ,(6531,'<p>9) &nbsp;Action (Who, What, When?)</p>')
        ,(6570,'<p><span style="color: rgb(29, 88, 196); font-family: Raleway, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 700; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: 2; text-align: start; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-decoration-thickness: initial; text-decoration-style: initial; text-decoration-color: initial; display: inline !important; float: none;">Blood-Borne Pathogens EXPIRATION DATE</span></p>')
go
```

**The field Question_Text2 should be used for the corrected Question_Text data.**

The data in Question_Text2 should be, see sample corrections below:

More samples of data can be made available.

```
| Question_id   |  question_text2 should read|                               
| ------------- | -------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| 6571          | Capstan Hoist EXPIRATION DATE                                              | 
| 6554          | Do you have the current Hazard certification to submit for verification?   |
| 6505          | SC - Utilities are Identified/Obtained Valid Locate Tickets/Are Guarded?   |
| 6569          | Authorized Climber and Rescue EXPIRATION DATE                              |
| 6531          | Action (Who, What, When?                                                   |
| 6570          | Blood-Borne Pathogens EXPIRATION DATE                                      |
| ------------- | -------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Karen

12/20/2021:

```
DECLARE @dtd nvarchar(max) = N'
 <!DOCTYPE xhtml
[
<!ENTITY nbsp   "&#160;"> <!-- no-break space = non-breaking space,
                                  U+00A0 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY iexcl  "&#161;"> <!-- inverted exclamation mark, U+00A1 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY cent   "&#162;"> <!-- cent sign, U+00A2 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY pound  "&#163;"> <!-- pound sign, U+00A3 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY curren "&#164;"> <!-- currency sign, U+00A4 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY yen    "&#165;"> <!-- yen sign = yuan sign, U+00A5 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY brvbar "&#166;"> <!-- broken bar = broken vertical bar,
                                  U+00A6 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY sect   "&#167;"> <!-- section sign, U+00A7 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY uml    "&#168;"> <!-- diaeresis = spacing diaeresis,
                                  U+00A8 ISOdia -->
<!ENTITY copy   "&#169;"> <!-- copyright sign, U+00A9 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY ordf   "&#170;"> <!-- feminine ordinal indicator, U+00AA ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY laquo  "&#171;"> <!-- left-pointing double angle quotation mark
                                  = left pointing guillemet, U+00AB ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY not    "&#172;"> <!-- not sign = angled dash,
                                  U+00AC ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY shy    "&#173;"> <!-- soft hyphen = discretionary hyphen,
                                  U+00AD ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY reg    "&#174;"> <!-- registered sign = registered trade mark sign,
                                  U+00AE ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY macr   "&#175;"> <!-- macron = spacing macron = overline
                                  = APL overbar, U+00AF ISOdia -->
<!ENTITY deg    "&#176;"> <!-- degree sign, U+00B0 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY plusmn "&#177;"> <!-- plus-minus sign = plus-or-minus sign,
                                  U+00B1 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY sup2   "&#178;"> <!-- superscript two = superscript digit two
                                  = squared, U+00B2 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY sup3   "&#179;"> <!-- superscript three = superscript digit three
                                  = cubed, U+00B3 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY acute  "&#180;"> <!-- acute accent = spacing acute,
                                  U+00B4 ISOdia -->
<!ENTITY micro  "&#181;"> <!-- micro sign, U+00B5 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY para   "&#182;"> <!-- pilcrow sign = paragraph sign,
                                  U+00B6 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY middot "&#183;"> <!-- middle dot = Georgian comma
                                  = Greek middle dot, U+00B7 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY cedil  "&#184;"> <!-- cedilla = spacing cedilla, U+00B8 ISOdia -->
<!ENTITY sup1   "&#185;"> <!-- superscript one = superscript digit one,
                                  U+00B9 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY ordm   "&#186;"> <!-- masculine ordinal indicator,
                                  U+00BA ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY raquo  "&#187;"> <!-- right-pointing double angle quotation mark
                                  = right pointing guillemet, U+00BB ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY frac14 "&#188;"> <!-- vulgar fraction one quarter
                                  = fraction one quarter, U+00BC ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY frac12 "&#189;"> <!-- vulgar fraction one half
                                  = fraction one half, U+00BD ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY frac34 "&#190;"> <!-- vulgar fraction three quarters
                                  = fraction three quarters, U+00BE ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY iquest "&#191;"> <!-- inverted question mark
                                  = turned question mark, U+00BF ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY Agrave "&#192;"> <!-- latin capital letter A with grave
                                  = latin capital letter A grave,
                                  U+00C0 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Aacute "&#193;"> <!-- latin capital letter A with acute,
                                  U+00C1 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Acirc  "&#194;"> <!-- latin capital letter A with circumflex,
                                  U+00C2 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Atilde "&#195;"> <!-- latin capital letter A with tilde,
                                  U+00C3 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Auml   "&#196;"> <!-- latin capital letter A with diaeresis,
                                  U+00C4 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Aring  "&#197;"> <!-- latin capital letter A with ring above
                                  = latin capital letter A ring,
                                  U+00C5 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY AElig  "&#198;"> <!-- latin capital letter AE
                                  = latin capital ligature AE,
                                  U+00C6 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Ccedil "&#199;"> <!-- latin capital letter C with cedilla,
                                  U+00C7 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Egrave "&#200;"> <!-- latin capital letter E with grave,
                                  U+00C8 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Eacute "&#201;"> <!-- latin capital letter E with acute,
                                  U+00C9 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Ecirc  "&#202;"> <!-- latin capital letter E with circumflex,
                                  U+00CA ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Euml   "&#203;"> <!-- latin capital letter E with diaeresis,
                                  U+00CB ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Igrave "&#204;"> <!-- latin capital letter I with grave,
                                  U+00CC ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Iacute "&#205;"> <!-- latin capital letter I with acute,
                                  U+00CD ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Icirc  "&#206;"> <!-- latin capital letter I with circumflex,
                                  U+00CE ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Iuml   "&#207;"> <!-- latin capital letter I with diaeresis,
                                  U+00CF ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY ETH    "&#208;"> <!-- latin capital letter ETH, U+00D0 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Ntilde "&#209;"> <!-- latin capital letter N with tilde,
                                  U+00D1 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Ograve "&#210;"> <!-- latin capital letter O with grave,
                                  U+00D2 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Oacute "&#211;"> <!-- latin capital letter O with acute,
                                  U+00D3 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Ocirc  "&#212;"> <!-- latin capital letter O with circumflex,
                                  U+00D4 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Otilde "&#213;"> <!-- latin capital letter O with tilde,
                                  U+00D5 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Ouml   "&#214;"> <!-- latin capital letter O with diaeresis,
                                  U+00D6 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY times  "&#215;"> <!-- multiplication sign, U+00D7 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY Oslash "&#216;"> <!-- latin capital letter O with stroke
                                  = latin capital letter O slash,
                                  U+00D8 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Ugrave "&#217;"> <!-- latin capital letter U with grave,
                                  U+00D9 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Uacute "&#218;"> <!-- latin capital letter U with acute,
                                  U+00DA ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Ucirc  "&#219;"> <!-- latin capital letter U with circumflex,
                                  U+00DB ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Uuml   "&#220;"> <!-- latin capital letter U with diaeresis,
                                  U+00DC ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Yacute "&#221;"> <!-- latin capital letter Y with acute,
                                  U+00DD ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY THORN  "&#222;"> <!-- latin capital letter THORN,
                                  U+00DE ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY szlig  "&#223;"> <!-- latin small letter sharp s = ess-zed,
                                  U+00DF ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY agrave "&#224;"> <!-- latin small letter a with grave
                                  = latin small letter a grave,
                                  U+00E0 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY aacute "&#225;"> <!-- latin small letter a with acute,
                                  U+00E1 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY acirc  "&#226;"> <!-- latin small letter a with circumflex,
                                  U+00E2 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY atilde "&#227;"> <!-- latin small letter a with tilde,
                                  U+00E3 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY auml   "&#228;"> <!-- latin small letter a with diaeresis,
                                  U+00E4 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY aring  "&#229;"> <!-- latin small letter a with ring above
                                  = latin small letter a ring,
                                  U+00E5 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY aelig  "&#230;"> <!-- latin small letter ae
                                  = latin small ligature ae, U+00E6 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY ccedil "&#231;"> <!-- latin small letter c with cedilla,
                                  U+00E7 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY egrave "&#232;"> <!-- latin small letter e with grave,
                                  U+00E8 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY eacute "&#233;"> <!-- latin small letter e with acute,
                                  U+00E9 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY ecirc  "&#234;"> <!-- latin small letter e with circumflex,
                                  U+00EA ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY euml   "&#235;"> <!-- latin small letter e with diaeresis,
                                  U+00EB ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY igrave "&#236;"> <!-- latin small letter i with grave,
                                  U+00EC ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY iacute "&#237;"> <!-- latin small letter i with acute,
                                  U+00ED ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY icirc  "&#238;"> <!-- latin small letter i with circumflex,
                                  U+00EE ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY iuml   "&#239;"> <!-- latin small letter i with diaeresis,
                                  U+00EF ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY eth    "&#240;"> <!-- latin small letter eth, U+00F0 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY ntilde "&#241;"> <!-- latin small letter n with tilde,
                                  U+00F1 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY ograve "&#242;"> <!-- latin small letter o with grave,
                                  U+00F2 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY oacute "&#243;"> <!-- latin small letter o with acute,
                                  U+00F3 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY ocirc  "&#244;"> <!-- latin small letter o with circumflex,
                                  U+00F4 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY otilde "&#245;"> <!-- latin small letter o with tilde,
                                  U+00F5 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY ouml   "&#246;"> <!-- latin small letter o with diaeresis,
                                  U+00F6 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY divide "&#247;"> <!-- division sign, U+00F7 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY oslash "&#248;"> <!-- latin small letter o with stroke,
                                  = latin small letter o slash,
                                  U+00F8 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY ugrave "&#249;"> <!-- latin small letter u with grave,
                                  U+00F9 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY uacute "&#250;"> <!-- latin small letter u with acute,
                                  U+00FA ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY ucirc  "&#251;"> <!-- latin small letter u with circumflex,
                                  U+00FB ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY uuml   "&#252;"> <!-- latin small letter u with diaeresis,
                                  U+00FC ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY yacute "&#253;"> <!-- latin small letter y with acute,
                                  U+00FD ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY thorn  "&#254;"> <!-- latin small letter thorn,
                                  U+00FE ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY yuml   "&#255;"> <!-- latin small letter y with diaeresis,
                                  U+00FF ISOlat1 -->
]>';
```

***-- BREAKS here:***

```
SELECT Question_Text 
FROM [stg].[Subform_Results] 
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(xml, @DTD + Question_Text, 2) IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Only those records which contain valid [XHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/XHTML#:%7E:text=XHTML%20is%20a%20term%20that,they%20should%20be%20served%20with) will successfully [TRY_CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql) to XML as documented.

> Returns a value cast to the specified data type if the cast succeeds; otherwise, returns null.

This appears to be the case for records 6571, 6569, and 6570 in your example.

Note that once you've cast the record to XML, your XPath query still needs to reference a valid path within the XML document. The example path you've given is not valid for any of the example documents you've supplied.

A valid path to return the data transform you want from records 6571, 6569, and 6570 is `.value('(/p/span/text())[1]','nvarchar(1000)')`. See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=39a1028973f49a9cded541b1d1b92a0a)

Note the difference - you need to probe into "span" as well for these XML documents. This may not be the case for every document you want to probe - even those that are cast-able to XML.

If you need help spot-checking what is or is not valid XML from your HTML sample data, you can try an [online prettifier](https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html) if your sample data is safe to be made public. As you can see below, it will either colorize and add whitespace to the XML to make the valid paths more apparent to a human eye...

[image: record 6570 as prettified valid XML]

...or give you a verbose reason why the text you've supplied cannot be converted.

[image: record 6531 is not valid XML: Unable to parse any XML input. Error on line 1: The entity "nbsp" was referenced, but not declared.]

Your success or failure in parsing will be case-by-case unless you get a better understanding of your source data. Data stored as XML (and JSON for that matter) documents can be arbitrary in a way that integers or dates are not. That can be useful or (in your case) annoying.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know XML or json and the data is not clearly xml or json or HTML, it is a mixture of all the above.  Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 2):

**You have two problems here:**

- You have some values which are nested in `span` nodes. It seems you actually want *all* inner text values, no matter how far nested. You can use `.query('//text()').value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')` for this.
- Your data is actually well-formed XHTML fragments. The key word here is *fragments*, it does not contain the relevant DTD specification, so that SQL Server can translate entities like `&nbsp;`. Even if it did specify the DTD, SQL Server will not download external specifications. You can instead add the full spec manually.
  If you feel you don't actually need all these entities, you can remove the ones that are not relevant to your data.

```sql
DECLARE @dtd nvarchar(max) = N'
 <!DOCTYPE xhtml
[
<!ENTITY nbsp   "&#160;"> <!-- no-break space = non-breaking space,
                                  U+00A0 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY iexcl  "&#161;"> <!-- inverted exclamation mark, U+00A1 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY cent   "&#162;"> <!-- cent sign, U+00A2 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY pound  "&#163;"> <!-- pound sign, U+00A3 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY curren "&#164;"> <!-- currency sign, U+00A4 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY yen    "&#165;"> <!-- yen sign = yuan sign, U+00A5 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY brvbar "&#166;"> <!-- broken bar = broken vertical bar,
                                  U+00A6 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY sect   "&#167;"> <!-- section sign, U+00A7 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY uml    "&#168;"> <!-- diaeresis = spacing diaeresis,
                                  U+00A8 ISOdia -->
<!ENTITY copy   "&#169;"> <!-- copyright sign, U+00A9 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY ordf   "&#170;"> <!-- feminine ordinal indicator, U+00AA ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY laquo  "&#171;"> <!-- left-pointing double angle quotation mark
                                  = left pointing guillemet, U+00AB ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY not    "&#172;"> <!-- not sign = angled dash,
                                  U+00AC ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY shy    "&#173;"> <!-- soft hyphen = discretionary hyphen,
                                  U+00AD ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY reg    "&#174;"> <!-- registered sign = registered trade mark sign,
                                  U+00AE ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY macr   "&#175;"> <!-- macron = spacing macron = overline
                                  = APL overbar, U+00AF ISOdia -->
<!ENTITY deg    "&#176;"> <!-- degree sign, U+00B0 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY plusmn "&#177;"> <!-- plus-minus sign = plus-or-minus sign,
                                  U+00B1 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY sup2   "&#178;"> <!-- superscript two = superscript digit two
                                  = squared, U+00B2 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY sup3   "&#179;"> <!-- superscript three = superscript digit three
                                  = cubed, U+00B3 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY acute  "&#180;"> <!-- acute accent = spacing acute,
                                  U+00B4 ISOdia -->
<!ENTITY micro  "&#181;"> <!-- micro sign, U+00B5 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY para   "&#182;"> <!-- pilcrow sign = paragraph sign,
                                  U+00B6 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY middot "&#183;"> <!-- middle dot = Georgian comma
                                  = Greek middle dot, U+00B7 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY cedil  "&#184;"> <!-- cedilla = spacing cedilla, U+00B8 ISOdia -->
<!ENTITY sup1   "&#185;"> <!-- superscript one = superscript digit one,
                                  U+00B9 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY ordm   "&#186;"> <!-- masculine ordinal indicator,
                                  U+00BA ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY raquo  "&#187;"> <!-- right-pointing double angle quotation mark
                                  = right pointing guillemet, U+00BB ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY frac14 "&#188;"> <!-- vulgar fraction one quarter
                                  = fraction one quarter, U+00BC ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY frac12 "&#189;"> <!-- vulgar fraction one half
                                  = fraction one half, U+00BD ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY frac34 "&#190;"> <!-- vulgar fraction three quarters
                                  = fraction three quarters, U+00BE ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY iquest "&#191;"> <!-- inverted question mark
                                  = turned question mark, U+00BF ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY Agrave "&#192;"> <!-- latin capital letter A with grave
                                  = latin capital letter A grave,
                                  U+00C0 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Aacute "&#193;"> <!-- latin capital letter A with acute,
                                  U+00C1 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Acirc  "&#194;"> <!-- latin capital letter A with circumflex,
                                  U+00C2 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Atilde "&#195;"> <!-- latin capital letter A with tilde,
                                  U+00C3 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Auml   "&#196;"> <!-- latin capital letter A with diaeresis,
                                  U+00C4 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Aring  "&#197;"> <!-- latin capital letter A with ring above
                                  = latin capital letter A ring,
                                  U+00C5 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY AElig  "&#198;"> <!-- latin capital letter AE
                                  = latin capital ligature AE,
                                  U+00C6 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Ccedil "&#199;"> <!-- latin capital letter C with cedilla,
                                  U+00C7 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Egrave "&#200;"> <!-- latin capital letter E with grave,
                                  U+00C8 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Eacute "&#201;"> <!-- latin capital letter E with acute,
                                  U+00C9 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Ecirc  "&#202;"> <!-- latin capital letter E with circumflex,
                                  U+00CA ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Euml   "&#203;"> <!-- latin capital letter E with diaeresis,
                                  U+00CB ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Igrave "&#204;"> <!-- latin capital letter I with grave,
                                  U+00CC ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Iacute "&#205;"> <!-- latin capital letter I with acute,
                                  U+00CD ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Icirc  "&#206;"> <!-- latin capital letter I with circumflex,
                                  U+00CE ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Iuml   "&#207;"> <!-- latin capital letter I with diaeresis,
                                  U+00CF ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY ETH    "&#208;"> <!-- latin capital letter ETH, U+00D0 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Ntilde "&#209;"> <!-- latin capital letter N with tilde,
                                  U+00D1 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Ograve "&#210;"> <!-- latin capital letter O with grave,
                                  U+00D2 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Oacute "&#211;"> <!-- latin capital letter O with acute,
                                  U+00D3 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Ocirc  "&#212;"> <!-- latin capital letter O with circumflex,
                                  U+00D4 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Otilde "&#213;"> <!-- latin capital letter O with tilde,
                                  U+00D5 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Ouml   "&#214;"> <!-- latin capital letter O with diaeresis,
                                  U+00D6 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY times  "&#215;"> <!-- multiplication sign, U+00D7 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY Oslash "&#216;"> <!-- latin capital letter O with stroke
                                  = latin capital letter O slash,
                                  U+00D8 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Ugrave "&#217;"> <!-- latin capital letter U with grave,
                                  U+00D9 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Uacute "&#218;"> <!-- latin capital letter U with acute,
                                  U+00DA ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Ucirc  "&#219;"> <!-- latin capital letter U with circumflex,
                                  U+00DB ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Uuml   "&#220;"> <!-- latin capital letter U with diaeresis,
                                  U+00DC ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY Yacute "&#221;"> <!-- latin capital letter Y with acute,
                                  U+00DD ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY THORN  "&#222;"> <!-- latin capital letter THORN,
                                  U+00DE ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY szlig  "&#223;"> <!-- latin small letter sharp s = ess-zed,
                                  U+00DF ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY agrave "&#224;"> <!-- latin small letter a with grave
                                  = latin small letter a grave,
                                  U+00E0 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY aacute "&#225;"> <!-- latin small letter a with acute,
                                  U+00E1 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY acirc  "&#226;"> <!-- latin small letter a with circumflex,
                                  U+00E2 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY atilde "&#227;"> <!-- latin small letter a with tilde,
                                  U+00E3 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY auml   "&#228;"> <!-- latin small letter a with diaeresis,
                                  U+00E4 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY aring  "&#229;"> <!-- latin small letter a with ring above
                                  = latin small letter a ring,
                                  U+00E5 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY aelig  "&#230;"> <!-- latin small letter ae
                                  = latin small ligature ae, U+00E6 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY ccedil "&#231;"> <!-- latin small letter c with cedilla,
                                  U+00E7 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY egrave "&#232;"> <!-- latin small letter e with grave,
                                  U+00E8 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY eacute "&#233;"> <!-- latin small letter e with acute,
                                  U+00E9 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY ecirc  "&#234;"> <!-- latin small letter e with circumflex,
                                  U+00EA ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY euml   "&#235;"> <!-- latin small letter e with diaeresis,
                                  U+00EB ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY igrave "&#236;"> <!-- latin small letter i with grave,
                                  U+00EC ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY iacute "&#237;"> <!-- latin small letter i with acute,
                                  U+00ED ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY icirc  "&#238;"> <!-- latin small letter i with circumflex,
                                  U+00EE ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY iuml   "&#239;"> <!-- latin small letter i with diaeresis,
                                  U+00EF ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY eth    "&#240;"> <!-- latin small letter eth, U+00F0 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY ntilde "&#241;"> <!-- latin small letter n with tilde,
                                  U+00F1 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY ograve "&#242;"> <!-- latin small letter o with grave,
                                  U+00F2 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY oacute "&#243;"> <!-- latin small letter o with acute,
                                  U+00F3 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY ocirc  "&#244;"> <!-- latin small letter o with circumflex,
                                  U+00F4 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY otilde "&#245;"> <!-- latin small letter o with tilde,
                                  U+00F5 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY ouml   "&#246;"> <!-- latin small letter o with diaeresis,
                                  U+00F6 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY divide "&#247;"> <!-- division sign, U+00F7 ISOnum -->
<!ENTITY oslash "&#248;"> <!-- latin small letter o with stroke,
                                  = latin small letter o slash,
                                  U+00F8 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY ugrave "&#249;"> <!-- latin small letter u with grave,
                                  U+00F9 ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY uacute "&#250;"> <!-- latin small letter u with acute,
                                  U+00FA ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY ucirc  "&#251;"> <!-- latin small letter u with circumflex,
                                  U+00FB ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY uuml   "&#252;"> <!-- latin small letter u with diaeresis,
                                  U+00FC ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY yacute "&#253;"> <!-- latin small letter y with acute,
                                  U+00FD ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY thorn  "&#254;"> <!-- latin small letter thorn,
                                  U+00FE ISOlat1 -->
<!ENTITY yuml   "&#255;"> <!-- latin small letter y with diaeresis,
                                  U+00FF ISOlat1 -->
]>'

SELECT
  CONVERT(xml, @DTD + Question_Text, 2).query('//text()').value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')
FROM tblQuestionsSample
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c09a8c3813c6af7c0356677edae78ac0)

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion, however, I am getting the following error when I try to implement within my db.  I see it works in DBFiddle, but not in my code:

Thanks for the great suggestion, however, I am getting the following error when I try to implement within my db.  Msg 9400, Level 16, State 1, Line 192
XML parsing: line 188, character 4002, unexpected end of input
XML DTD has been stripped from one or more XML fragments.  External subsets, if any, have been ignored.

Comment: You would have to show us the values that are failing, as the ones you have given do work. Use `WHERE TRY_CONVERT(xml, @DTD + Question_Text, 2) IS NULL`

Comment: I am still getting the error When the code attempts to run the Select query, that is were it breaks.  See edited portion above with the highlighted area.

Comment: No just `SELECT Question_Text FROM [stg].[Subform_Results] WHERE TRY_CONVERT(xml, @DTD + Question_Text, 2) IS NULL`

Comment: Thanks, tried your suggestion of change to the query, however, the is still not working with the same issue.

Comment: That's simply impossible. `SELECT Question_Text` cannot fail, neither can `TRY_CONVERT(xml`. Unless you are also selecting `CONVERT(xml ....` or you have something else in your query. Please copy the above query *exactly*

Comment: Charlie, I did copy the query and it still failed.  I was wondering in declaring the @DTD should have the < within the code?  See the code posted above within the code.

Comment: Yes it has to be in one batch with the `DECLARE`. Your code that you posted has `SELECT CONVERT(xml, @DTD + Question_Text, 2) FROM...` it should be just `SELECT Question_Text FROM ...`

Comment: Still not working?

Comment: error msg:
Msg 9400, Level 16, State 1, Line 195
XML parsing: line 188, character 4002, unexpected end of input
XML DTD has been stripped from one or more XML fragments.  External subsets, if any, have been ignored.

Completion time: 2021-12-20T12:36:22.6969535-05:00

Comment: I honestly can't replicate, see eg https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9c067ab6300185d47dc8e944c2467a6f where the result from `try_convert` is `null`. Can you create a https://dbfiddle.uk with your data and failing query?